# Representatives of a collection of sets

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose that a collection of sets $A_{1},A_{2},\dots,A_{n}$ satisfies $|\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{k}A_{{i}_{j}}|\geq k+1$ for every $1\leq k <n$ and $\{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k\} \subset [n]$, and that $x \in A_i$.

Show that the collection has a system of distinct representatives in which $x$ represents $A_i$.

It was suggested to me that graphs may be useful in solving this but I can't see how.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the bipartite graph $G = (S,T,E)$, where the vertices in $S = \{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ correspond to the sets $A_1,\dots,A_n$, the vertices in $T = \{u_y : y \in \cup A_j\}$ correspond to the elements of $\cup A_j$, and edges denote set membership, so that $u_yv_j$ is an edge precisely if $y \in A_j$.

In this language, what you would like to show is that there is a matching covering $S$ which contains the edge $u_xv_i$. In other words, there is a matching covering $S-v_i$ in $G - v_i - u_x$. Now you just have to decipher what the condition on the sizes of the $A_i$ say for this graph and use a well-known result about matchings in bipartite graphs (which hopefully you are familiar with).